# jQuery: Click event inside of a click event

Tags: jquery

I have a div.
There is a button in this div that empties the div and fills it with new content.

The problem lies here, when the div is filled with new content I cannot call the click() function on the any of the elements that have filled this div. What am I doing wrong?

The block of code all the way to the bottom is the problematic one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        function newGame(){
            //Empty the game window of contents.
            $('#previewWindow').empty();

            //Add the following HTML to the game window.
            $('#previewWindow').append("<div id='spriteBox' align='center'><img id='sprite1' src='images/sprites/172(noSelect).png' border='0'/><img id='sprite2' src='images/sprites/88(noSelect).png' border='0' /><img id='sprite3' src='images/sprites/196(noSelect).png' border='0' /><div id='info' align='center'>TEST</div></div>");

            //Hover effects for Sid's character.
            $('#sprite1').hover(function(){$(this).attr('src', 'images/sprites/172.png');$('#crumbling').get(0).play();},function(){$(this).attr('src','images/sprites/172(noSelect).png');}
            );

            //Hover effects for Grim's character.
            $('#sprite2').hover(function(){$(this).attr('src', 'images/sprites/88.png');$('#crumbling').get(0).play();},function(){$(this).attr('src', 'images/sprites/88(noSelect).png');}
            );

            //Hover effects for Falas's character.
            $('#sprite3').hover(function(){$(this).attr('src', 'images/sprites/196.png');$('#crumbling').get(0).play();},function(){$(this).attr('src','images/sprites/196(noSelect).png');}
            );
        };

        //Execute the following code block if New Game is clicked.
        $('#newGame').click(function(){
            newGame();
        });

        //Execute the following code block if Sid is clicked.
        $('#sprite1').click(function(){
            alert('Hello');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to delegate event. Don't forget IDs must be unique on document context. https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have attached the click handlers directly to the buttons inside the div.

when the div content is reloaded, you get new buttons without the click handlers.

you would want to use event delegation at this point, which means you attach the handlers to the content div instead, so they are not lost when its emptied.

i assume your content div is `"previewWindow"`
so here is how you do event delegation:

```
    $('#previewWindow').on('click','#newGame',function(){
        newGame();
    });

    //Execute the following code block if Sid is clicked.
    $('#previewWindow').on('click','#sprite1',function(){
        alert('Hello');
    });
```

what it basically means is, whenever you click inside `#previewWindow` on any element with `id="newGame"`, it calls the new game.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, a thousand times thank you! Very fast responses and all so helpful. Wish I was had high enough rep to upvote you all.

This one being the most clear, direct, and easy-to-follow. I will be selecting it as the answer as soon as it lets me(like 4 minutes or so).

Answer (score 0):

When you add data *after* you register a click-event, the click-event will not apply to the data that came after you registered it.

To fix this, you can use the [jQuery("#container").on(event, selector, handler(event))](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to register events on elements that haven't been added yet.

```
$('#previewWindow').on('click', '#sprite1', function(){
    alert('Hello');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the `$('#sprite1').click()` event inside your `newGame()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function newGame(){
        //Empty the game window of contents.
        $('#previewWindow').empty();

        //Add the following HTML to the game window.
        $('#previewWindow').append("<div id='spriteBox' align='center'><img id='sprite1' src='images/sprites/172(noSelect).png' border='0'/><img id='sprite2' src='images/sprites/88(noSelect).png' border='0' /><img id='sprite3' src='images/sprites/196(noSelect).png' border='0' /><div id='info' align='center'>TEST</div></div>");

        //Execute the following code block if Sid is clicked.
        $('#sprite1').click(function(){
            alert('Hello');
        });

        //Hover effects for Sid's character.
        $('#sprite1').hover(function(){$(this).attr('src', 'images/sprites/172.png');$('#crumbling').get(0).play();},function(){$(this).attr('src','images/sprites/172(noSelect).png');}
        );

        //Hover effects for Grim's character.
        $('#sprite2').hover(function(){$(this).attr('src', 'images/sprites/88.png');$('#crumbling').get(0).play();},function(){$(this).attr('src', 'images/sprites/88(noSelect).png');}
        );

        //Hover effects for Falas's character.
        $('#sprite3').hover(function(){$(this).attr('src', 'images/sprites/196.png');$('#crumbling').get(0).play();},function(){$(this).attr('src','images/sprites/196(noSelect).png');}
        );
    };

    //Execute the following code block if New Game is clicked.
    $('#newGame').click(function(){
        newGame();
    });

});
```

Comment: This would work, still it would cause it to call the `.click()` event handler many times, and is not optimal as opposed to the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('#sprite1').on('click', function() {
        alert('Hello');
     });
});
```